# How to create customized event with Xamarin.Forms.Maps in F#?

Tags: c#, f#, xamarin.forms.maps

How to create a customized event with Xamarin.Forms.Maps in F#? I did a version in C#, but try to convert into F# unsuccessfully. Please feel free to comment how to convert into F#. Thank you.

**Version in C#**

```
public class MyMap : Map
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ZoomLevelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ZoomLevel), typeof(Distance), typeof(MainPageMap), new Distance());

        public MyMap()
        {
            this.PropertyChanged += (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                MyMap map = sender as MyMap;
                if (map.VisibleRegion != null)
                {
                    this.ZoomLevel = map.VisibleRegion.Radius;
                    // Console.WriteLine("Xamarin Forms Map Radius: {0} Kilometers | {1} Meters | {2} Miles.", ZoomLevel.Kilometers, ZoomLevel.Meters, ZoomLevel.Miles);
                }
            };
        }

        public Distance ZoomLevel
        {
            get { return (Distance)GetValue(ZoomLevelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ZoomLevelProperty, value); }
        }

    }
```

According to the "[Microsoft's document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/events)", I try to convert into F#.

```
namespace ProjectA.Controls

open System
open System.ComponentModel
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Maps

type MyMap() =
    inherit Map()
   
    static let ZoomLevelProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ZoomLevel", typeof<Distance>, typeof<MyMap>, new Distance())

    member this.ZoomLevel
        with get () = this.GetValue ZoomLevelProperty :?> Distance
        and set (value: Distance) = this.SetValue(ZoomLevelProperty, value)

    member this.PropertyChanged(sender: Object, e: PropertyChangedEventArgs) =
        let map:MyMap = sender :?> MyMap
        if (map.VisibleRegion <> null) then this.ZoomLevel <- map.VisibleRegion.Radius
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @JL0PD Cannot update the customized property "this.ZoomLevel"

Comment: Is it a runtime error?

Comment: @ it isn't a runtime error.